# Cassandra - Data Design Solution for Login Service

Tags: performance, cassandra

I need your help to design structure for simple login service. It contains about 100.000.000 customers and each one can have about 10 different logins - this results 1.000.000.000 different logins.

Each customer contains following data:

- one to many login names as string, max 20 UTF-8 characters long
- ID as long - one customer has only one ID
- gender
- birth date
- name
- password as MD5

Login process needs to find user by login name.

Data in Cassandra is replicated - this is necessary to obtain all required login data in single call. Also usually we expect low write traffic and heavy read traffic - round trips for reading data should be avoided.

Below I've described two possible cassandra data models based on example: we have two users, first user has two logins and second user has three logins

**A) Skinny rows**

- row key contains login name - this is the main search criteria
- login data is replicated - each possible login is stored as single row which contains all user data - 10 logins for single customer create 10 rows, where each row has different key and the same content

```
    // first 3 rows has different key and the same replicated data
        alfred.tester@xyz.de {
          id: 1122
          gender: MALE
          birthdate: 1987.11.09
          name: Alfred Tester
          pwd: e72c504dc16c8fcd2fe8c74bb492affa  
        },
        alfred@aad.de {
          id: 1122
          gender: MALE
          birthdate: 1987.11.09
          name: Alfred Tester
          pwd: e72c504dc16c8fcd2fe8c74bb492affa  
        },
        alf@dd.de {
          id: 1122
          gender: MALE
          birthdate: 1987.11.09
          name: Alfred Tester
          pwd: e72c504dc16c8fcd2fe8c74bb492affa  
        },

    // two following rows has again the same data for second customer
        manfred@xyz.de {
          id: 1133
          gender: MALE
          birthdate: 1997.02.01
          name: Manfredus Maximus
          pwd: e44c504ff16c8fcd2fe8c74bb492adda  
        },
        roberrto@xyz.de {
          id: 1133
          gender: MALE
          birthdate: 1997.02.01
          name: Manfredus Maximus
          pwd: e44c504ff16c8fcd2fe8c74bb492adda  
        }
```

**B) Rows grouped by alphabetical prefix**

- Number of rows is limited - for example first letter from login name
- Each row contains all logins which benign with row key - row with key 'a' contains all logins which begin with 'a'
- Data might be unbalanced, but we avoid skinny rows - this might have positive performance impact (??)
- to avoid super columns each row contains directly columns, where column name is the user login and column value is corresponding data in kind of serialized form (I would like to have is human readable)

```
    a {
        alfred.tester@xyz.de:"1122;MALE;1987.11.09;
                                 Alfred Tester;e72c504dc16c8fcd2fe8c74bb492affa",

        alfred@aad.de@xyz.de:"1122;MALE;1987.11.09;
                                 Alfred Tester;e72c504dc16c8fcd2fe8c74bb492affa",

        alf@dd.de@xyz.de:"1122;MALE;1987.11.09;
                                 Alfred Tester;e72c504dc16c8fcd2fe8c74bb492affa"
      },

    m {
        manfred@xyz.de:"1133;MALE;1997.02.01;
                  Manfredus Maximus;e44c504ff16c8fcd2fe8c74bb492adda"    
      },

    r {
        roberrto@xyz.de:"1133;MALE;1997.02.01;
                  Manfredus Maximus;e44c504ff16c8fcd2fe8c74bb492adda"    

      }
```

Which solution is better, especially for read performance? Do you have better idea?

Comment: What are your criteria for "better"? Performance, clarity, extensibility, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a [crosspost](http://www.mail-archive.com/user@cassandra.apache.org/msg18808.html), but I'll go ahead and answer your question here as well.

If you're always using login names as your lookup key, then you're essentially building a key-value store.  Cassandra certainly makes a great key-value store if you use it like one, which would be your skinny row model.

Wide rows are used when you have somewhat more complex queries to answer, like when you're dealing with time-series data, or lists, or sets. The reason that wide row data models are sometimes described as being "more performant" is because they offer extremely good performance for those slightly more complex types of queries.  Trying to use skinny row models to answer those types of queries can be very inefficient.

But there's no need to warp your key-value store to make it fit in a wide-row model -- it will perform perfectly well with skinny rows.